# Capture everything between constants

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to capture everything between every instance of `User.` and a space, including `User.`

So given a test string of

```
psdojfsdf User.sdoinwpoiev.spoinwelsdknonfsjfnw ldnkfwwdf sdf User.sdoinffon.ribwgg
```

I want it to capture `User.sdoinwpoiev.spoinwelsdknonfsjfnw` and `User.sdoinffon.ribwgg`

I've gotten this far: `/(User\..*)\s/`, but this captures everything until the last space.

Comment: `User.User.User.User.sdoinwpoiev `, Do you care about that?

Comment: Ok, in the real world that don't happen, then you shouldn't worry about the `\.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I believe is best is to tell it to match everything but space rather than everything. That gives:

```
/(User\.\S*)/
```

Another alternative is to use a non-greedy match, but I think that's less clear:

```
/(User\..*?)\s/
```

Comment: Actually, anytime you have to use `.*?` there is something wrong with the way its done.

Comment: @sln Probably true mostly, but it's useful to be able to understand the syntax as well as having the opportunity to evaluate the merits of various alternatives. :)

Comment: Maybe, but for beginners, its good not to encourage general lazy quantifiers (especially used with `.`), but to show a better way and start them towards good habits.

Answer (score 1):

use a non-greedy quantifier:

```
/(User\..*?)\s/
```

See [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for details about greediness of repetition operators.

Note that this won't work if the word ends at the end of the input string, if there's no space at the end. Coenwulf's answer may be better, as it doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *? non-greedy zero or more

```
/User\.[^   \s]*?/g
```

Also if you want to force it to have something between the dot and the space

```
/User\.[^   \s]+?/g
```

Or if you want it to be alphanumeric

```
/User\.[a-zA-Z_$]+?[a-zA-Z_$0-9]*?( |   |\s)/g
```

If you want to allow line breaks between the dot and the property identifier

```
/User\.[a-zA-Z_$]+?[a-zA-Z_$0-9]*?(\n| |    |\s)/gm
```

Comment: Why do you have `|` in the character set?

Comment: You don't need both space and `\s` in the character set, since `\s` includes space.

Comment: @Barmar /s didn't work in some browsers as space neither tab, I can't remember which version of Chrome made me crazy debugging that, so I've got the reflex of using it always.

Comment: You still haven't explained why you're also excluding `|`.

Comment: I'm very skeptical of problems with `\s`, there's way too much code that depends on it.

Comment: `[^ | |\s]` I don't think this means Not tab OR space OR whitespace, does it? There is no alternation construct in character classes, just literals and sub-classes right?

Comment: @Barmar Oh! yeah, big mistake with the | in []. fixed

Comment: @sln yeah, I've made a mistake there, it fixed now. Sorry, it is late night here

Comment: Not a problem. I think the SO editor turned your tab into spaces `[^ \s]` Its always better to use the symbol for the tab instead `[^ \t\s]`

Comment: On a side note - Most modern engines support the horizontal whitespace class `\h` which is `[ \t]`

Comment: @sln I had problems in the past with \s and \t, I just type them literaty cause I'm sure it will work. The \h sound cool, however if only new engines will support it I will avoid it for now

Comment: I would try `\h` whenever you can (if available), it avoids having to do some nasty stuff like `[^\S\r\n]` when just doing line spacing in Multi-Line mode regex's.